# Cleaner 'for each' loop for registering scripts in functions.php

Tags: php, functions

I'm looking for a elegant way to register a ton of scripts I have sitting in a js directory on my server without having to sit and type them all out.

> I found this [question here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/195864/most-elegant-way-to-enqueue-scripts-in-function-php-with-foreach-loop) but it is 3 years old, I'm basically
>   after a similar solution and I would like to know if the following
>   code I have adapted from the original question is suitable for the
>   task?
>
> Or alternatively, if there a better solution at all?

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'theme_register_scripts' );
function theme_register_scripts() {

    $path = '/assets/js'; 
    $scripts = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..')); 

    foreach ( $scripts as $k=>$v ) 
         wp_register_script( $k, get_template_directory_uri() . $v );
}
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Are there no dependencies for these scripts?

Comment: Just Jquery. basically they're components.

Comment: You shouldn't need to type them all out, you can use tooling to generate the list, which would also be faster in production as it prevents the need to scan the directory

Comment: Sorry tooling? Could you point me in the direction of a manual?